# asp.net core docker image "aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim"

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, docker-image

I recently created a new asp.net core 2.2 project and while making changes to the dockerfile I noticed the visual studio template used a new base image that I am unfamiliar with and unable to find documentation on. Can someone explain what this "stretch-slim" image is and how it differs from the aspnet image I expected to see?

**Actual**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
```

**Expected**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

stretch-slim refers to the base debian image used by the aspnet image. **Stretch** is the development codename for Debian 9 and **Slim** is the minimal prerequisites required by debian and excludes additional tool and packages from the image.

The .NET Core 2.2 Docker images are currently all available in four flavors, depending on the OS image they're based on: debian:stretch-slim, ubuntu:bionic, alpine:3.8, and alpine:3.9. There are also ARM32 versions of the debian and ubuntu images. Debian is the default OS used by the .NET Core docker images.

Asp.net core chooses the debian:stretch-slim as the base image and this provides the asp.net images with the smallest OS foot print possible.

The following tags all refer to the same image
2.2.6-stretch-slim, 2.2-stretch-slim, 2.2.6, 2.2

References:

- https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-net-core-mcr-docker-files-runtime-vs-aspnet-vs-sdk/#3-mcr-microsoft-com-dotnet-core-aspnet-2-2-3
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch
- https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md
- https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/7e4359dfe6e1bc649fbb58de273da3d35bf864f1/2.2/aspnet/stretch-slim/amd64/Dockerfile

Answer (score 7):

I came across this answer searching for what `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster` image was. After a little digging, it turns out that **Buster** is the code name for Debian 10 that has just been released recently. May be helpful for someone.

Comment: Well, I was searching for what do these `buster` docker images Microsoft create and I found this. Thanks.